# localhost Apache Very Slow

Tags: networking, apache-httpd

I have my RPi set up as an Apache2 Webserver.

When I curl to localhost with my network cable unplugged I get a response in <1s
However, once I connect the network cable - the time for response goes to more like 20s.

My host file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
```

Any help? I suspect it's the lookup that's taking ages - but why is this happening when the host defines the IP?